# How to pick only one value in a query if it occurs continuosly

Tags: sql, oracle

```
   SNO       Status
     1      Entering    
     2      Entering
     3      Assigned    
     4      Denied   
     5      Assigned
```

The above values are part of a query's output.
The requirement is the Status column should return only one 'Entering' as it occurs continuously(for Sno 1 and 2).
Other rows here should not be affected. For ex, 'Assigned' - as it does not occur continuously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lag()` with some logic checking should do what you want:

```
with q as (< your query here> )
select sno, status
from (select q.*, lag(status) over (order by sno) as prev_status
      from q
     ) q
where prev_status is null or prev_status <> status;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `SNO`s are sequential with no gaps, you can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM MyTable x WHERE t.SNO=x.SNO-1 AND t.Status=x.Status
)
```

A correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause looks at `SNO-1`, rejecting rows with matching `Status`.

Comment: "Assuming...no gaps" is not a realistic assumption in most Oracle databases.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak `SNO` may very well be user-assigned, in which case the assumption of no-gap in the sequence is no longer unreasonable.